# How can I go about checking whether a particular Stage is an instance of a particular Controller Class

Tags: java, javafx, instanceof

How can I go about checking whether a particular `Stage` is an instance of a particular Controller Class?

For example:

I have a Stage `stage`, and the only information I have is that the `stage.getScene().getRoot()` is an instance of a VBox.

I, however, could get the Controller class of a Stage via:

```
public Object loadController(String url) {
    try {
        loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(url));
        loader.load();
        return loader.getController();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The main problem I have is that there is no way to get the `url` of the `stage.getScene().getRoot()`

Comment: Controllers are not instances of Stage. Not sure what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: This is probably not very helpful, but if you think you need to do something like this, you are just approaching things in the wrong way. (This is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).) Perhaps create a [MCVE] showing what you are trying to achieve, and someone can suggest a way to solve the actual problem.